# Did Apple deprecate web app start-up-images?

Tags: ios, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been doing lots of work creating several images for my web apps. Until iOS 8 they worked very good as a start-up-image for my bookmarked web apps on the iOS HomeScreen. Suddenly, after iOS 9 they are not working anymore... no matter what device is used

## Example

```
    <link href="/apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue with iOS 9:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23924